# Absolute Value and Systems of Inequalities (HW Question)

Tags: calculus, inequality, absolute-value

Question: Use the definition of absolute value and systems of inequalities to prove that for any real numbers x and c, and any positive real number δ, the given statement is true:

$|x−c|<δ⇔x∈(c−δ,c+δ)$

I am very confused on how to do this question as I am unable to get what the question is asking me. This question has been listed in one of my homework questions so I am very lost. If anyone can help me out, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: What do you mean by 'def. of absolute value and systems of inequalities'? You should provide these details from your class as context, since what you'd like to prove is trivial, otherwise others cannot undestand.

Answer (score 0):

As with any bi-implication, it is asking you to prove two things:

1. That *if* $|x-c|\lt \delta$, **then** $x$ must be in the interval $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$; and
2. That *if* $x$ is in the interval $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, **then** it must be the case that $|x-c|\lt\delta$.

It also instructs you to prove these facts using “the definition of absolute value and systems of inequalities”. Exactly what that means for your course is for you to know and not for us to guess; there are many different ways in which the basic properties can be set forth (usually any small number of assertions can be used to establish all the others), so exactly which one is being used in your course will be key in how you prove this.